# Loading contents of a webpage sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I'm trying to use the following content slider on my Django application, http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentslider.htm The problem I'm trying to solve is that I'll have close to a hundred 'contentDiv' (the pages that'll be loaded), and was wondering if it is possible for them to be loaded sequentially such that the first one gets loaded first and displayed to the user, and the other 'contentDiv' load after that so the user doesn't have to wait for all of the stuff to load before he can see the page. Sorry if my question is vague, or if my title is misleading!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hold those contentDivs in a separate page and then load them each in sequence using AJAX:

```
var loaded = true;
for (var i = 0 ; loaded ; i++) {
    var div = 'contentDiv' + i;
    $(body).append('<div id=' + div + '></div>');
    $('#contentDiv' + i).load('otherpage.html #' + div, function(response, status, xhr) { 
        if (status == 'error') {
            loaded=false;
        }});  // assumes you have the #contentDiv[i] already in otherpage.html
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now as (sequential) pagination. It is easiest to accomplish this by using jQuery.

You can find a demo [here](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/35/index.html), and the article that accompanies it [here](http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-easy-pagination-with-jquery/).